# Como fazer um script aceitar o autocompletar em bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

Digamos que eu tenha um script que peça uma entrada do usuário como apresentado a seguir

```
Digite o caminho do arquivo:
```

Como faço esse input autocompletar o caminho dos diretorios no linux? Eu preciso disso para evitar erros de digitação

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais fácil de fazer isso é incluir um script de shell em /etc/bash_completion.d/. A estrutura básica deste arquivo é uma função simples que executa a conclusão e, em seguida, a invocação de complete que é um compilador de bash. Em vez de entrar em detalhes sobre como usar complete, sugiro que você leia uma Introdução ao [Bash Completion](https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1). A Parte 1 cobre o básico e a Parte 2 entra em como você faria escrever um script de conclusão.